# Updating Statement in SQL/PSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

i am new in the SQL field and i have a dumb question. Lets pretend I have a table in my database, which contains the following information:

```
ID        name     food
1         Max      apple
2         Anne     banana
3         Tom      kiwi
```

lets pretend that this is a kindergarden group that ate these foods. 2 Hors later Max ate strawberries and i want ot add this in the list as well. I want the list to look like this:

```
ID        name     food
1         Max      apple, strawberries
2         Anne     banana
3         Tom      kiwi
```

I already tried it with the UPDATE statement in SQL, but all of them want an if statement, which i personally dont understand. Does someone has an idea, how i can do it in one statement? Thanks!

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a string!  You need a separate table with one row per `name`/`food`.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: lets pretend that the food are in a different tabel. apple has a food_ID of 1 and the strwaberries have food_ID 2. In the big table there would still be a 1, 2 . I want to add the second value to the table with the UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing you could do is to use several tables:

- Users (ID, name)
- Food (ID, name)
- UserFoods (ID (optional), user_id, food_id)

Then, you could associate as many food as you want to each user. You could also add a datetime column to UserFoods if needed, etc.

*You would not use UPDATE but SET and DELETE statements...

---

Said that, the answer to your question would be this:

```sql
UPDATE users 
   SET food = CONCAT(food, ', ', 'strawberries') 
 WHERE name = 'Max';
```

Explanation:
It selects the table `users` and it concatenates the `current food`, a comma and space `,` and `strawberries` to the food field of the user called `Max`.

**I've used the user name but you should use the ID since there could be a lot of users called Max**...